# Why and how use Canvas.saveLayer to do alpha animation or gain performance

Tags: android, android-canvas, graphics2d

I'm new to graphics in android java.
I've come across `Canvas.saveLayer(...)` `Canvas.restore(...)` and the usefulness
of these operations (a.o. in terms of performance) escape me completely. Are layers
thus saved across subsequent **lockCanvas ~ unlockCanvasAndPost** cycles ? Or,
what's the point in saving and restoring a 'buffered bitmap' for every frame ?

Some are also mentioning to use these layers to do f.i. an alpha animation (re-compositing ???), but I don't seem to find a clear example of how to do that either ...

OR

Am I utterly and absolutely barking up the wrong tree here ?

Answer (score 3):

Canvas.saveLayer lets you retarget the rendering to an offscreen buffer. The buffer can be a bitmap or a GPU texture depending on how you set the view's layer type - either software or hardware rendering (i.e LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE or LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html))

This buffer is composited into the previous target when you call the corresponding restoreToCount. So this allows you to do various visual effects like fading (ie. alpha animation).

Ideally you want to do alpha animation using hardware layer because alpha can be hardware accelerated.

You rarely call canvas.setLayer directly to set or animate alpha. You are either going to use view.setAlpha or if animating then  view.animate().alpha(0), both of which internally end up calling setAlphaLayer on the canvas.

So the only thing you would want to do is make sure to set the layer type to View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE (if supported on the device otherwise software layer through LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE) before starting alpha animation and then removing it at the end of the animation.

In 4.0 you can do:

```
view.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
view.animate().alpha(0).setListener (new AnimationListener() {
             public void onAnimationEnd (Animator animation) {
                   view.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
             }
});
```

In 4.1, this is simplified as just:
`view.animate().alpha(0).withLayer();`